# Include specific Angular module

Tags: angularjs, module

I'm trying to include a github module [angular-drag-drop](http://github.com/ggoodman/angular-drag-drop). I'm new to angular and I fail. The readme shows an example of using webpack or browserify, but I'm not using those. I've also filed an issue, but I wanted to ask it here as well.

odds.js:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('pokerApp', ['angular-drag-drop']);
})();
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-drag-drop.min.js"></script>
    <script src="odds.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app = "pokerApp" ng-init = "cards = ['As','Ks','Qs','Js','Ts','9s','8s','7s','6s','5s','4s','3s','2s',
                                 'Ah','Kh','Qh','Jh','Th','9h','8h','7h','6h','5h','4h','3h','2h',
                                 'Ad','Kd','Qd','Jd','Td','9d','8d','7d','6d','5d','4d','3d','2d',
                                 'Ac','Kc','Qc','Jc','Tc','9c','8c','7c','6c','5c','4c','3c','2c']"> 

        <!--<div drag-container>KKKKKKKKKKKK</div>-->

        <!--
        <div drag-container="model"
            on-drag-start="ctl.handleDragStart($event, data)"
            on-drag-end="ctl.handleDragEnd($event, data)"
        ></div>-->
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The file angular-drag-drop.min.js was copied from [the github repo](https://github.com/ggoodman/angular-drag-drop/tree/master/dist). The error I get is:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module pokerApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angular-drag-drop due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-drag-drop' is not available! You  either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I also tried with 'AngularDragDrop' instead of 'angular-drag-drop' but I get the same error.

Comment: are you sure you have included `angular-drag-drop` in your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer has posted the answer in the issue. I needed to import "filearts.dragDrop" and not import require.js. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

It need `require.js` to load modules, also I looked at API, I think the module name should be

```
learts.dragDrop
```

instead of

```
angular-drag-drop
```

**odds.js:**

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('pokerApp', ['learts.dragDrop']);
})();
```

Comment: Are you sure I need require.js? Because that's in the src and not in the dist code. I use the dist code. I changed it to learts.dragDrop but I get the same error (still without require.js).

Comment: @AlbertHendriks I guessed that by looking at the code..could you create a plunkr so that I can dig into it..

Comment: it does look like you need require